# Extract 2nd page of each document and merge into a single document with Ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

I have a set of pdf files from which I would like to:

- extract the 2nd page of each
- merge all the 2nd pages into a single document

I know how to do each of these independently with Ghostscript (generating a bunch of temporary 1-page PDF files on the way), but is there any way to do it in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried ?

Provided you want the *same* page(s) from every file then this:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf \
   -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2 \
    input1.pdf input2.pdf
```

should work.

Please note that my usual caveats apply; pdfwrite is not 'manipulating' the source PDF files, it is fully interpreting them to produce lists of drawing primitives, which are then reassembled to form a brand new PDF file. At no point are you 'extracting' or 'merging' PDF files, the content of the output file(s) bears no relation, other than visual appearance, to the input file(s).

Comment: Thanks, it worked. You may want to remove the reference to "my usual caveats" in your answer though, since I don't think any reader knows what they are.

Comment: They do if they read posts here, I put these in very regularly when answering any question to do with pdfwrite :-) Also, I did reiterate them, to the point of nausea for any regular reader I suspect.